# Omnipay - Mollie test transactions not showing on dashboard

Tags: php, codeigniter, omnipay, mollie

I'm trying to implement Mollie API via omnipay php library.

However i have few questions which i cant understand by myself.

1. When i chose the payment status to be returned as Cancelled and click on Further to your webshop Mollie redirects me to the payment methods page (the page where you choose what payment method to use), is this correct?
2. If no.1 is correct how should i test failed transaction?
3. After successful transaction i cant see any transactions in the dashboard? Does on test mode the transactions are not shown in the dashboard?
4. When its on live mode and no payment modes are passed only the checked payment modes from the dashboard will be shown, right?
5. I cant find a way to test the webhooks, i'm passing the the notifyUrl param but this url is never called, how can i test this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you been able to figure this out? You can always contact Mollie at info@mollie.com for questions like this.

But to answer them:

> 1. When i chose the payment status to be returned as Cancelled and click on Further to your webshop Mollie redirects me to the payment methods page (the page where you choose what payment method to use), is this correct?

This is the expected behaviour when you don't send the payment method (and optionally the issuer, depending on the payment method) yourself. The consumer gets the chance to retry the payment with another method.

> 2. If no.1 is correct how should i test failed transaction?

You can press the 'cancel' button to test cancelled payments.

Another option is to specify the payment method. In that case you will be redirected to your website immediately after you selected 'cancelled' as payment status.

> 3. After successful transaction i cant see any transactions in the dashboard? Does on test mode the transactions are not shown in the dashboard?

It could be that this was not available at the time you asked your question, but now you can switch the 'test mode' toggle next to the 'refresh' and 'export' buttons.

> 4. When its on live mode and no payment modes are passed only the checked payment modes from the dashboard will be shown, right?

In live mode, only the enabled payment methods in your profile are shown. In test mode, all payment methods are active.

> 5. I cant find a way to test the webhooks, i'm passing the the notifyUrl param but this url is never called, how can i test this?

For test payments, the webhook should be called also. Make sure that the url is publicly visitable, so no local development URLs. When you need to use local url's, you could use tools like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).